# Hot to make InputStream - Reader conversion?

Tags: java, input, java-io

Theoretical problem in Java:
We have written an Probe class and we have a Probe *probe* object with these methods:

```
public InputStream getStream();
public void readAll( Reader r );
```

We have to call the `readAll(Reader r)` method on *probe*, with the getStream() method's return value. So we have to make a conversion. I would use InputStremReader class, like this:

```
probe.readAll( new InputStreamReader( probe.getStream() );
```

Does it work or not?

Comment: If you're asking whether `InputStreamReader` converts an `InputStream` to a `Reader`, the answer is yes.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Didn't try it, it is only for an exam, and we do exams on paper